# Passing value to the function in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following situation:

`SELECT TestPkg.getData(123) FROM dual;`

returns correct result, but

```
SELECT TestPkg.getData(SELECT TO_NUMBER('123') FROM dual) FROM dual;
```

gives error as missing expression, why is that so? How to tackle with such situation where we are passing value to function which is dependent on value from query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To evaluate a select result you need brackets:

```
SELECT TestPkg.getData( (SELECT TO_NUMBER('123') FROM dual) ) FROM dual;
```

One pair for the function call, one for the evaluation of the select result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
SELECT TestPkg.getData(TO_NUMBER('123')) FROM dual;
```